# C++ ::std::enable_if and virtual

Tags: c++, c++11

I've had a scan for answers but ... they seem to be silly questions.

I am perfectly happy with and fully understand (I can't stress that enough) with why it makes no sense to have a template virtual member of a class.

Consider the abstract base class `List` (With... `LinkedList` and `ArrayList` deriving from it)

If the type the list stores has a concept of identity (not a string or int, something without any sensible "==", I wont bring POD up here) you would want a method
`virtual bool contains(T& what) const;` and
`virtual int index(T& what) const;`
however if it is a type without identity, like strings or numbers you would want:
`virtual int countOccurrences(T& what) const;` and
`virtual int find(T& what, int occurrence=0) const;`

Say.

This cannot be done using `::std::enable_if` so you must do something like:

```
template<class T, bool HAS_IDENTITY> class List;
template<class T> class List<false> {
    virtual int countOccurrences(T& what) const=0;
    virtual int find(T& what, int occurrence=0) const=0;
    /*other stuff*/
};

template<class T> class List<true> {
    virtual bool contains(T& what) const =0;
    virtual int index(T& what) const =0;
    /*other stuff*/
};
```

This isn't that bad, but there is a lot of code duplication, and I only get wet (against DRY) when I have to.

If I hide the common code in a base class it is a bit nicer.

My question involves scaling with this approach, here we have one bool, giving 2 specialisations, suppose I have n bools then there are 2^n specialisations, I can't see a case where I'd need more than 4, but that is still 16 classes involved! 8 for 3, it's not very nice.

Suppose I have an enum and a bool, then I have 2*enum count specialisations.

It grows far to quickly.

Previously we've used macros to define classes and it'd use the `##` operator in the class name to essentially mangle it as a template would. I must say though I quite like `enable_if` and friends now though...

Is there a pattern someone can show me that'd solve this?

Comment: So *concept of identity* means any type that can be compared using `operator==`? I don't get how you can `countOccurrences` for a type that's not equality comparable, but I suppose that's not relevant to answering your question.

Comment: @Praetorian http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_%28object-oriented_programming%29 strings don't have an identity, if I give you two strings at different locations in memory they are not distinct, an `==` can be sensibly defined. A type **with** identity makes things that may be bit-for-bit identical distinct, consider for example records in a table of names and ages, an "id" or "identity" can separate two people with the same name of the same age. In a GUI program I can have two identical frames open, they have identity (and are clearly distinct), this is why sizeof(struct {}) ==1.

Comment: So @Praetorian in this case, if the list is storing things with an identity, such as frames for example, `countOccurrences` and `find` are silly, `contains` and `index` make perfect sense. The concept becomes a bit fuzzy when real world things like "performance" come into play :P Generally speaking: anything that is passed by value (in C++) lacks identity, if you use a reference or pointer that is identity.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't add `const` to those reference parameters?

Comment: `template<class T> class List<false>` should be `template<class T> class List<T, false>`

Comment: Could you give an example of one additional such property that you need to combine with `HAS_IDENTITY`? Currently, it looks like you could use multiple inheritance to collect a number of virtual functions from class templates with two specializations each.

Comment: @Dyp "because I wrote it in the question box to demonstrate a point", then "" and yes, "INTEGRAL_DOMAIN", which basically means it can be ordered, you also have partial orders too... Another specialisation would be for when identity is present on a reference type, then you want to use the address of.

Comment: @dyp It somehow appears that the question opener is not in time-pressure for finding answers. I'd appreciate if you had a look at my ansatz below; I'm currently working at a property decorator design sth not so far away from that (skip any notion of "virtual"), and would like to know your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Just a q&d hack, but it should provide some hints.

<strike>*I somehow know that one could even get rid of that ugly "Dummy" param, but I don't see that right now*</strike>

**EDIT Jul 6th**

I made that ansatz a little more seamless to use.
A compile-time test of the Concept "Identity", what the question opener is apparently aiming at, would require compile-time testing of

```
//T t1, t2;
(t1 == t2) == (&t1 == &t2);
```

and that is imo not possible.
Thus I introduced the notion of *Feature lists* for easy manual assignment of such features.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <type_traits>
#ifdef __GNUG__
#include <cxxabi.h>
auto type_str = [](const std::type_info& ti) {
    int stat;
    return abi::__cxa_demangle(ti.name(), 0, 0, &stat);
};
#else 
#warning untested
auto type_str = [](const std::type_info& ti) {
     return ti.name();
};
#endif


typedef int Feature;

const Feature HAS_IDENTITY = 1;
const Feature HAS_FOOBAR = 2;
const Feature HAS_NO_IDENTITY = -HAS_IDENTITY;
const Feature HAS_NO_FOOBAR = -HAS_FOOBAR;
const Feature _TERM_ = 0;


template<typename T, Feature F>
struct has_feature : std::false_type {};

template<int N , int M>
struct is_greater {
    constexpr static bool value = N > M;
};

namespace  detail {
    template<class T, Feature... Fs> struct List {};  // primary template
    template<class T, Feature F>
    struct List<T,F> {};

    template<class T, Feature F, Feature... Fs> 
    struct List<T,F,Fs...> 
        : virtual public 
                std::conditional<
                    has_feature<T,F>::value,
                    List<T, F>,
                    List<T, -F> 
                >::type,
        virtual public 
                std::conditional<
                    is_greater<sizeof...(Fs),0>::value,
                    List<T, Fs...>, 
                    List<T, _TERM_>
                > ::type {};

    template<class T> struct List<T, _TERM_> {};

    template<class T> 
    struct List<T,HAS_NO_FOOBAR> {
        virtual std::string hello() const /* = 0;*/ {
            return std::string("\"What the foo is FOOBAR?\", askes ") + type_str(typeid(T));
        }
    };

    template<class T> 
    struct List<T,HAS_FOOBAR> {
        virtual std::string hello() const /* = 0;*/ {
            return std::string("\"For sure I'm FOOBAR\", says ") + type_str(typeid(T));
        }
    };


    template<class T> 
    struct List<T,HAS_NO_IDENTITY> {
        virtual int index(const T& what) const /* = 0;*/ {
            return 137;
        }
    };

    template<class T> 
    struct List<T,HAS_IDENTITY> {
        virtual int index(const T& what) const /* = 0;*/ {
            return 42;
        }
    };

    template<typename T>
    using Feature_Aware_List = List<T,HAS_IDENTITY,HAS_FOOBAR, /* all Features incuding*/_TERM_>;
} //namespace detail

template<typename T>
using List = detail::Feature_Aware_List<T>;

struct Gadget { 
    bool operator== (const Gadget& rhs) const {
        return this == &rhs;
    }
};     

struct Gimmick { 
    bool operator== (const Gimmick& rhs) const {
        return this == &rhs;
    }
};     

template<Feature F>
struct FeatureList {};

template<>
struct FeatureList<HAS_IDENTITY>
    : public Gadget, 
      public Gimmick 
      /**/ 
{};

#include <valarray>
template<>
struct FeatureList<HAS_FOOBAR>
    : public std::valarray<float> 
      /**/ 
{};

template<class T> 
struct has_feature<T, HAS_IDENTITY> 
    : public std::conditional<
        std::is_base_of<T, FeatureList<HAS_IDENTITY>>::value,
        std::true_type,
        std::false_type
    >::type {};

template<class T> 
struct has_feature<T, HAS_FOOBAR> 
    : public std::conditional<
        std::is_base_of<T, FeatureList<HAS_FOOBAR>>::value,
        std::true_type,
        std::false_type
    >::type {};


int main() {
    List<Gadget> l1 ;
    List<std::valarray<float>> l2;
    std::cout << l1.hello() << " #" << l1.index(Gadget()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << l2.hello() << " #" << l2.index(std::valarray<float>()) << std::endl;

}
```

Output:

```
"What the foo is FOOBAR?", askes Gadget #42
"For sure I'm FOOBAR", says std::valarray<float> #137
```

*It should be self-explaining that no specific "list" functionality is implemented, that's mock-only*

Answer (score 1):

You may use template policies:

```
template<class T, bool HAS_IDENTITY> class ListIdentityPolicy;
template<class T> class ListIdentityPolicy<T, false> {
    virtual int countOccurrences(T& what) const = 0;
    virtual int find(T& what, int occurrence = 0) const = 0;
};
template<class T> class ListIdentityPolicy<T, true> {
    virtual bool contains(T& what) const = 0;
    virtual int index(T& what) const = 0;
};

template<class T, bool HAS_FOOBAR> struct ListFoobarPolicy;
template<class T> struct ListFoobarPolicy<T, false> {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};
template<class T> struct ListFoobarPolicy<T, true> {
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};

template <class T> class List
    : public ListIdentityPolicy<T, HasIdentity<T>::value>
    , public ListFoobarPolicy<T, HasFoobar<T>::value>
{
public:
    /*other stuff*/
};
```

`HasIdentity` and `HasFoobar` are type traits which you would define, each containing a `static const bool value` indicating whether `T` has the corresponding property.

---

Or, you could give `List` a non-virtual public API, and hide the dynamic dispatch in the implementation:

```
template <class T> class List
{
public:
    enum Impl {
        LinkedList = 0,
        ArrayList,
    };
    List(Impl i) : pimpl(makePimpl(i)) {}
    List(List const& other) : pimpl(other.pimpl->clone())
    List& operator=(List const& other) { pimpl = other.pimpl->clone(); }

    int count(T& what) const
    { static_assert(! HasIdentity<T>::value, "oops"); return pimpl->count(what); }
    int find(T& what, int n = 0) const
    { static_assert(! HasIdentity<T>::value, "oops"); return pimpl->find(what, n); }
    bool contains(T& what) const
    { static_assert(HasIdentity<T>::value, "oops"); return pimpl->contains(what); }
    int index(T& what) const
    { static_assert(HasIdentity<T>::value, "oops"); return pimpl->index(what); }
    void foo()
    { static_assert(! HasFoobar<T>::value, "oops"); pimpl->foo(); }
    void bar()
    { static_assert(HasFoobar<T>::value, "oops"); pimpl->bar(); }

private:
    struct AbstractPimpl
    {
        virtual std::unique_ptr<AbstractPimpl> clone() const = 0;
        virtual int count(T& what) const = 0;
        virtual int find(T& what, int n = 0) const = 0;
        virtual bool contains(T& what) const = 0;
        virtual int index(T& what) const = 0;
        virtual void foo() = 0;
        virtual void bar() = 0;
    };

    struct LinkedListPimpl : public AbstractPimpl
    {
        std::unique_ptr<AbstractPimpl> clone() override;
        int count(T& what) const override;
        int find(T& what, int n = 0) const override;
        bool contains(T& what) const override;
        int index(T& what) const override;
        void foo() override;
        void bar() override;
        /* ... */
    };

    struct ArrayListPimpl : public AbstractPimpl
    {
        std::unique_ptr<AbstractPimpl> clone() override;
        virtual int count(T& what) const override;
        virtual int find(T& what, int n = 0) const override;
        virtual bool contains(T& what) const override;
        virtual int index(T& what) const override;
        virtual void foo() override;
        virtual void bar() override;
        /* ... */
    };

    std::unique_ptr<AbstractPimpl> pimpl;

    static std::unique_ptr<AbstractPimpl> makePimpl(Impl i) {
        switch (i) {
            LinkedList: default:
            return std::make_unique<LinkedListPimpl>();
            ArrayList:
            return std::make_unique<ArrayListPimpl>();
        }
    }
};
```